# is there any tool which can autogenerate html form from database field

Tags: mysql, spring, forms

I have database table and i use netbeans to auto generate POJO from it.

Now is it possible that html form can also bve auto generated with input elements with name being the table fields.

If something can generate sprinng jsp form with path mapping to field names , that will be excellent.

It don't look hard , i think i can create the php script which can do that. but just asking if there is already something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo), that can generate the whole web app, including forms, from your database.

Comment: u mean to say that if i have one database table with 10 fields then can roo generate the form fields automatically

Comment: @Pasha: yes, and roo will generate the whole application too (Entitys, Controller, Forms, Infrasturcture), but you can extract the things you need.

Comment: @Pasha: the best Roo Introduction are the "10 minutes" presentation by Ben Alex (http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Introducing-Spring-Roo) and the soring roo reference http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/intro.html

Comment: I studied documentation i could not find any syntax where i mention the database table name , and the html form is generated from already existed table. however i have seen that u mention the table name and field name in roo commandline and then it generates but from already existing table

Comment: @Pasha: it is a feature of the actual version 1.1.0: the roo command is: "database reverse engineer" -- have a look at the Blog item for 1.1.0 Release: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/10/27/spring-roo-1-1-0-is-released/